# Проблемы с работой preloader vue.js

Tags: vue.js, vue-router, компоненты, loader

Всем привет. Пытаюсь сделать отображение прелоадера при переходах между компонентами. Использую этот [прелоадер](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-loading-overlay). Как делаю, создал файл loader.js с таким содержанием:

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import Loading from 'vue-loading-overlay';
import 'vue-loading-overlay/dist/vue-loading.css';

Vue.use(Loading);

let loader = Vue.$loading.show({
    loader: 'dots',
    color: '#5D00FF',
    zIndex: 999,
}); 
function loaderStart() {
    loader;
}
function loaderEnd() {
    loader.hide();
}

export default {loaderStart, loaderEnd}
```

Сам файл импортирую в index.js и в нем прописываю когда хочу вызывать старт и конец лоадера но почему то прилоадер не запускается(Без условия в `beforeResolve` прилоадер рабочий, проверял). Вот содержимое index.js:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Router from 'vue-router'
import Authorization from '@/components/Authorization'
import Main from '@/components/Main'
import loader from './loader'

Vue.use(Router)

const router = new Router({
    routes: [
    {
        path: '/',
        name: 'Main',
        component: Main,
    },
    {
        path: '/authorization',
        name: 'Authorization',
        component: Authorization
    }
  ]
})
router.beforeResolve((to, from, next) => {
    if(to.path) {
        loader.loaderStart()
    }
    next()
});
router.afterEach((to, from) => {
    loader.loaderEnd()
});
export default router;
```

Подскажите пожалуйста,  в чем может быть проблема?

Comment: Ну вы хотя бы проконсольте. И найдите часть кода в которой не работает. И функции необходимо вызывать по событиям компонента.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ваш код с минимальными изменениями:

```
// loader.js

function loaderStart() {
  loader.isActive = true;
}

function loaderEnd() {
  loader.isActive = false;
}
```

```
// index.js

router.afterEach((to, from) => {
  setTimeout(function() {
    loader.loaderEnd();
  }, 888);
});
```

---

Ниже вариант, основанный на [сообщении](https://github.com/ankurk91/vue-loading-overlay/issues/21#issuecomment-433784174) автора плагина **ankurk91**. В снипете, чтобы места много не занимал.

```js
import Vue from 'vue';
import Loading from 'vue-loading-overlay';
import 'vue-loading-overlay/dist/vue-loading.css';

// Устанавливаем плагин `Loading`,
// используя глобальный метод `use` с
// передачей дополнительных параметров
Vue.use(Loading, {
  loader: 'dots',
  color: '#5D00FF',
  zIndex: 999,
});

// Создадим пустую ссылку.
let loader = null;

// Показать прелоадер.
function showLoader() {
  // Используем локальную функцию
  // для скрытия прелоадера.
  hideLoader();

  // Показываем прелоадер,
  // используя метод `show` самого плагина,
  // установленного глобально во Vue.
  loader = Vue.$loading.show();
}

// Скрыть прелоадер.
function hideLoader() {
  // Если ссылка не пуста,
  // т.е. существует предыдущий прелоадер.
  if (loader) {
    // а) скрываем прелоадер,
    // используя метод `hide` компонента плагина.
    loader.hide();

    // б) удаляем ссылку на объект.
    loader = null;
  }
}

// Экспортируете как вам удобнее:
// объектом или отдельными функциями.
export default {
  loaderStart: showLoader,
  loaderEnd: hideLoader
}
```

---

- `show` - это метод плагина, возвращающий [`instance`](https://github.com/ankurk91/vue-loading-overlay/blob/master/src/js/api.js) экземпляра приложения Vue;
- `hide` - это метод [компонента](https://github.com/ankurk91/vue-loading-overlay/blob/a992dd8d5985c0f1e8fd7963060011b31f35ff04/src/js/Component.vue#L107).

---

Используемые ресурсы, при написании ответа: [Vue API](https://ru.vuejs.org/v2/api/#Vue-extend), [How to use it with vue router](https://github.com/ankurk91/vue-loading-overlay/issues/21), [Исследование бездны null и undefined в JavaScript](https://www.frontender.info/exploring-the-abyss-of-null-and-undefined-in-javascript/).